# How to Get MAC Address of VMs with Azure PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure

Does anyone know how to get Mac address of vms in Azure through Azure PowerShell?
i know i can get it with WMI or something else inside the VM, but i don't know how can i do that without logging on the VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface` command and the `MacAddress` property the resulting object has:

```
(Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName %rgName%).MacAddress
```

this will list all the macs of the network interfaces in a resource group, to be more specific you could add the `-Name` parameter.

```
(Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName %rgName% -Name %nicName%).MacAddress
```

Comment: thanks a lot:)  didn't notice that MacAddress property already contained in the result object